# Placing overlapping text on a page

Tags: tables, positioning

How can I make text or tables overlap?

- Can I place the letters "a" and "b" at the same location (based on left and downward alignment)?
- Can I place two tabular environments in exactly the same place (one is above the other), but not inside `float`, `figure`, or `table` environments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\llap` and `\rlap` which make boxes of zero width; in the case of tables, I first boxed them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent A\llap{B}

\noindent\rlap{A}B

\newsavebox\boxa
\savebox\boxa{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
text1 \\
text2 \\
text3 \\
\end{tabular}}

\newsavebox\boxb
\savebox\boxb{\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
column1a & column2a \\
column1b & column2b \\
\end{tabular}}

\noindent\usebox\boxb\llap{\usebox\boxa}

\noindent\rlap{\usebox\boxa}\usebox\boxb

\end{document}
```

[image]